# VBA transposing an array with parameters

Tags: excel, vba

I've managed to record all changes my team has done and in order to use it further I'll need to transpose the table into format supported by our systems. I was able to transpose one row but there are hundreds in my file so my code was useless.

My input table look like this

[image: Input]

My goal for output looks like this

[image: Output]

I've managed to transpose the whole table from tutorial (Essential Excel), however it doesn't fit my needs.

```
Sub TransposeTest()

Dim wks As Worksheet, wks2 As Worksheet
Dim MyArray As Variant
Dim LastRow As Integer, LastColumn As Integer
Dim StartCells As Range

Set wks = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
Set wks2 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Transpose")
Set StartCell = wks.Range("A2")

LastRow = wks.Cells(wks.Rows.Count, StartCell.Column).End(xlUp).row
LastColumn = wks.Cells(StartCell.row, wks.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

MyArray = wks.Range(StartCell, wks.Cells(LastRow, LastColumn)).Value2

MyArray = WorksheetFunction.Transpose(MyArray)

wks2.Range("a2", wks2.Cells(LastColumn, LastRow)).Value = MyArray

End Sub
```

I've been advised to use array for months and loop through each row however I unable to achieve it.

Comment: This transformation is called unpivoting and the easiest way to do it is by using Power Query. I think you select the first column with the values and find `Unpivot Column` and continue playing with it. It is part of Excel since version 2016 when it was called `Get & Transform`. In my 2019 version, in the `Data` tab, you select `From Table/Range`.

Comment: Can you edit your question and supply your existing situation as editable? I would like to try something, but I do not want to manually reproduce it...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can obtain your desired output using `Power Query`, available in Windows Excel 2010+ and Office 365 Excel

- Select some cell in your original table
- `Data => Get&Transform => From Table/Range` or `From within sheet`
- When the PQ UI opens, navigate to `Home => Advanced Editor`
- Make note of the Table Name in Line 2 of the code.
- Replace the existing code with the **M-Code** below
- Change the table name in line 2 of the pasted code to your "real" table name
- Examine any comments, and also the `Applied Steps` window, to better understand the algorithm and steps

***M Code***

```
let

//Change table name in next row to the actual table name in your workbook
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],

//set the data types
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{
        {"Index", Int64.Type}, {"Person", Int64.Type}, {"Dept", Int64.Type}, 
        {"Jan", Int64.Type}, {"Feb", Int64.Type}, {"Mar", Int64.Type}, 
        {"Apr", Int64.Type}, {"May", Int64.Type}, {"Jun", Int64.Type}, 
        {"Jul", Int64.Type}, {"Aug", Int64.Type}, {"Sep", Int64.Type}, 
        {"Oct", Int64.Type}, {"Nov", Int64.Type}, {"Dec", Int64.Type}, 
        {"Time", type datetime}, {"User", type text}},"en-150"),

//Unpivot the Month columns
    #"Unpivoted Other Columns" = Table.UnpivotOtherColumns(#"Changed Type", 
        {"Index", "Person", "Dept", "Time", "User"}, "Month", "Sales"),

//Transform "Month" column to "MonthNum.YearNum
//Not sure where the year should come from.
//   for now will just hard code at as 2022
//   but could use a different method.
    mnthCol = Table.TransformColumns(#"Unpivoted Other Columns", {"Month", each 
        Date.ToText(Date.FromText("1-" & _ & "-2022"),"M.yyyy"),type text}),

//Reorder the columns
    #"Reordered Columns" = Table.ReorderColumns(mnthCol,{"Index", "Person", "Dept", "Month", "Sales", "Time", "User"}),

//Rename the columns as per your example
    rename = Table.RenameColumns(#"Reordered Columns",{
        {"Time","STMP"},
        {"Dept","Depr"}
    })
in
   rename
```

***Original Data***
[image]

***Partial Results***
[image]

Comment: many thanks, I'll try and will let you know.

Comment: is there any way how the year can be adjusted dynamically? We're planning 6 months ahead so in July I'll have to set January to 2023. Do you think it's manageable?

Comment: @Eternity92 Depends on the actual rule. For example, one could easily extract the year from a date that is 6 months from **today**. Or you could extract it from your date column if that is a reliable method.

Comment: I see, in order to do it I'll need to use `Date.Month(DateTime.LocalNow() + 6` , however I'm not sure how to achieve automatic change to 2023. Thank you in advance.

Comment: @Efernity92 If that will be your algorithm, you can compute the **year** with somthing like: `year = DateTime.ToText(Date.AddMonths(DateTime.LocalNow(),6),"yyyy")` and then use that in place the hard-coded year in the `mnthCol = ` step.

Comment: I've tried your solution however 2022 remains. My goal is that once we're close to another year, January will change to 01.2023. M-code  `mnthCol = Table.TransformColumns(#"Unpivoted Other Columns", {"MNTH", each 
        Date.ToText(Date.FromText("1-" & _ & DateTime.ToText(Date.AddMonths(DateTime.LocalNow(),6),"yyyy")),"MM.yyyy"),type text}),`  Many thanks

Comment: @Efernity92 Since you are adding six (6) months to today, and today is in the month of April, the year in the Month column will remain as 2022.

Comment: I see, I understand now. However is there a way how to set remaining months of current year to -.2022 and jan, feb, mar to -.2023? I was thinking to have 2 mnthCols, one for current, second for next year or something like    `mnthCol = Table.TransformColumns(#"Unpivoted Other Columns", {"MNTH", each 
        Date.ToText(Date.FromText("1-" & _ & "-2022")),"MM.yyyy"}, {Date.ToText(Date.FromText("7-" & _ & "-2023"),"M.yyyy"),type text}),` but none of these options seem to work. Thank you for your patience.

Comment: @Efernity92 You can do that either way. Depends on how you want to design it. Especially since you already have an answer to your question in this thread, I suggest you figure out specifically what you want; put something together; and, if you can't figure it out, pose it as a new question. This is getting too involved to be handled in comments.

Answer (score 3):

Please, try the next code. It should be very fast, even for large ranges. It uses arrays and works only in memory, the result being dropped at once:

```
Sub TransposeData()
  Dim sh As Worksheet, shTr As Worksheet, lastR As Long, arr, arrfin, ArrH, i As Long, k As Long, j As Long
  
  Set sh = ActiveSheet
  Set shTr = sh.Next  'use here the sheet you need to return.
                      'if the next sheet is empty you can let the code as it is
  lastR = sh.Range("A" & sh.rows.count).End(xlUp).row 'last row
  
  arr = sh.Range("A1:Q" & lastR).value                          'place the range in an array for faster iteration
  ReDim arrfin(1 To UBound(arr) * 12 + 1, 1 To 7): k = 1        'redim the final array dimensions
  ArrH = Split("Index,Person,Dept,Month,Sales,STMP,User", ",")  'create an array from the header strings
  'place the headers in the first row of the final array:
  For i = 0 To UBound(ArrH): arrfin(k, i + 1) = ArrH(i): Next: k = k + 1
  'build the final array:
  For i = 2 To UBound(arr)
        For j = 1 To 12
            arrfin(k + j - 1, 1) = arr(i, 1): arrfin(k + j - 1, 2) = arr(i, 2): arrfin(k + j - 1, 3) = arr(i, 3)
            arrfin(k + j - 1, 4) = j & "." & Year(Date): arrfin(k + j - 1, 5) = arr(i, j + 3)
            arrfin(k + j - 1, 6) = arr(i, 16): arrfin(k + j - 1, 7) = arr(i, 17)
        Next j
        k = k + j - 1 'reinitialize k variable for the next data row
  Next i

  'drop the final array content at once, and do some formatting:
  With shTr.Range("A1").Resize(UBound(arrfin), UBound(arrfin, 2))
        .value = arrfin
        .rows(1).Font.Bold = True
        .EntireColumn.AutoFit
        For i = 7 To 9
            .Borders(i).Weight = xlThin
            .Borders.LineStyle = xlContinuous
        Next
 End With

 MsgBox "Ready..."
End Sub
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/242312/discussion-on-answer-by-faneduru-vba-transposing-an-array-with-parameters).