# PowerQuery - dynamic change of the year

Tags: excel, powerquery

I'm unpivoting and transposing (input) in order to have (output) formatted for internal systems. Solution provided by @RonRosenfeld in [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71178905/vba-transposing-an-array-with-parameters/71190909) solved the issue.

However year for output is hard coded to 2022, which is fine until we'll reach 2nd half of the year, then I'd like to dynamically change new months to 2023 i.e. 01.2023, 02.2023...

I couldn't come up with dynamical solution so I tried "Fiscal year" which doesn't work even after modifying data type.

[Input]
[image: [2]]

[Output]

[image: [3]]

```
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],

    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{
        {"Index", Int64.Type}, {"Person", Int64.Type}, {"Dept", Int64.Type}, 
        {"Jan", Int64.Type}, {"Feb", Int64.Type}, {"Mar", Int64.Type}, 
        {"Apr", Int64.Type}, {"May", Int64.Type}, {"Jun", Int64.Type}, 
        {"Jul", Int64.Type}, {"Aug", Int64.Type}, {"Sep", Int64.Type}, 
        {"Oct", Int64.Type}, {"Nov", Int64.Type}, {"Dec", Int64.Type}, 
        {"Time", type datetime}, {"User", type text}},"en-150"),

    #"Unpivoted Other Columns" = Table.UnpivotOtherColumns(#"Changed Type", 
        {"Index", "Person", "Dept", "Time", "User"}, "Month", "Sales"),

    mnthCol = Table.TransformColumns(#"Unpivoted Other Columns", {"MNTH", each 
        Date.ToText(Date.FromText("1-" & _ & DateTime.ToText(Date.AddMonths(DateTime.LocalNow(),8),"yyyy")),"MM.yyyy"),type text}),
    #"Changed Type1" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(mnthCol,{{"MNTH", type date}}),

    FC = Table.AddColumn(#"Changed Type1", "Fiscal Month", each if Date.ToText(Date.Month([MNTH])) >=7 then Date.ToText(Date.Month([MNTH]))-6 else Date.ToText(Date.Month([MNTH]))+6),

    #"Reordered Columns" = Table.ReorderColumns(mnthCol,{"Index", "Person", "Dept", "Month", "Sales", "Time", "User"}),

    rename = Table.RenameColumns(#"Reordered Columns",{
        {"Time","STMP"},
        {"Dept","Depr"}
    })
in
   rename
```

Comment: You can use a named range on one of your excel sheets to hold the fiscal year. https://www.excelguru.ca/blog/2014/11/26/building-a-parameter-table-for-power-query/ explains how to work with them

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adjustment to the [original solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71178905/vba-transposing-an-array-with-parameters/71190909) is to change

```
mnthCol = Table.TransformColumns(#"Unpivoted Other Columns", {"Month", each 
    Date.ToText(Date.FromText("1-" & _ & "-2022"),"M.yyyy"),type text}),
```

to something along the lines of

```
   mnthCol = Table.TransformColumns(#"Unpivoted Other Columns", {"Month", each 
    if  Date.Month(Date.FromText("1-" & _ & "-1900"))<7 then 
    Date.ToText(Date.FromText("1-" & _ & "-2023"),"M.yyyy")
   else 
   Date.ToText(Date.FromText("1-" & _ & "-2022"),"M.yyyy")
    ,type text}),
```

but you'd have to set the 7 dynamically somehow to determine which months are in which year